# How to do distributed Principal Components Analysis + Kmeans using Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means, pca

I need to run [Principal Components Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) and [K-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) on a large-ish dataset (around 10 GB) which is spread out over many files.  I want to use [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org) for this since it's known to be fast and distributed.

I know that  Spark [supports PCA](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-dimensionality-reduction.html#principal-component-analysis-pca) and also [PCA + Kmeans](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/mllib-sfmachinelearning-140509003134-phpapp02/95/largescale-machine-learning-with-apache-spark-17-638.jpg?cb=1399596202).

However, I haven't found an example which demonstrates how to do this with many files in a distributed manner.

Comment: You can read your file via `textFile`, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397907/spark-context-textfile-load-multiple-files) and then process resulting RDD as you wish

Comment: @Odomontois Yeah, I also found [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397907/spark-context-textfile-load-multiple-files) shortly after posting mine. I wasn't sure if that was the idiomatic way of doing it in Spark. Have you done that before in Spark?

Comment: I'm doing code like `sc.textFile(files mkString ",")` pretty often