# pyspark - multiple input files into one RDD and one output file

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark

I have a wordcount in Python that I want to run on Spark with multiple text files and get ONE output file, so the words are counted in all files altogether. I tried a few solutions for example the ones found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029873/how-to-read-multiple-text-files-into-a-single-rdd) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397907/spark-context-textfile-load-multiple-files/23407980), but it still gives the same number of output files as the number of input files.

```
rdd = sc.textFile("file:///path/*.txt")
input = sc.textFile(join(rdd))
```

or

```
rdd = sc.textFile("file:///path/f0.txt,file:///path/f1.txt,...")
rdds = Seq(rdd)
input = sc.textFile(','.join(rdds))
```

or

```
rdd = sc.textFile("file:///path/*.txt")
input = sc.union(rdd)
```

don't work. Can anybody suggest a solution how to make one RDD of a few input text files?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you clarify what "don't work" means?

Comment: It means the same as a few lines above - the program returns the same number of output files as the number of input files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should load all the files matching the pattern.

```
rdd = sc.textFile("file:///path/*.txt")
```

Now, you **do not need to do any union**. You have only one RDD.

Coming to your question - `why are you getting many output files`. The number of output files depends on number of `partitions` in the `RDD`. When you run word count logic, your resultant RDD can have more than 1 partitions. If you want to save the RDD as single file, use `coalesce` or `repartition` to have only one partition.

The code below works, taken from [Examples](http://spark.apache.org/examples.html).

```
rdd = sc.textFile("file:///path/*.txt")
counts = rdd.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
...              .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
...              .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)

counts.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("res.csv")
```

Comment: Does it mean that all the actions and operations run on several partitions and only the output is merged into one thing? For example the word 'the' is counted separately for each partition (file) and there will be several values for the same word in the output file? If yes - perhaps `coalesce()` could be used as first or somewhere at the beginning?...

Comment: No, whenever u perform action/transformation you get new RDD. In above-mentioned example, counts Rdd is resultant RDD. A word 'the' will appear only once in counts RDD.

Comment: You can checkout this presentation for more details - https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/mohitgargk/spark-101-58162162

Comment: Your solution works perfectly @Mohitt. Thank you for that and for the presentation.